# Error on pdf-tools installation

Tags: pdf-tools

My emacs version is 25.2 but i got the same issues on 24.3:
When i run M-x package-install-file RET pdf-tools-0.70.tar RET in emacs i get:

```
pdf-annot.el:32:1:Error: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, tablist
Compiling file /home/alex/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-0.70/pdf-cache.el at Sun     Apr 23 16:19:22 2017
Error: Opening output file: Cannot overwrite file, /home/alex/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-0.70/pdf-cache.elc
```

`Make install-package`  doesn't work either.

Comment: pdf-tools-0.70 is two years old. You can get the latest version (~ 2 weeks old) directly from melpa. Is there a reason you're using this outdated version?

Comment: I installed it through melpa and it worked, there was no reason for installing that version, i just thought that it was the most recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdf-tools` depends on the `tablist` package (which you can find on MELPA, for example).  I can't help you with the second error.